# How to restore the deleted EFS certificate

Tags: windows-7, encrypting-file-system

I accidently deleted EFS (Encrypting File System) certificate by using the properties form in the Internet Explorer and now I don't have access to my encrypted files.

Is there any option to restore the certificate?

I can see this certificate in the system but when I imported it back, it is not shown that the certificate has a private key.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my case, I found another version of the same certificate in certmgr.msc and luckily this version has a private key. I exported the certificate and then imported it into the personal folder. The access to the encrypted files was restored.